# Geometry and circles

Tags: geometry

[image: Diagram]

> In this figure, $A$ is the centre, $D,F,B$ are colinear, $E,G,D$ are colinear, $\angle ECA=30°$, and $\angle DFE=95°$. I am required to find $\angle AED$.

---

I calculated that $\angle EBC=60°$, and other measures. But I cannot seem to use $\angle EFD$, and am am unable to solve.

Please help.

Comment: Is G a point of intersection of radius AC and diagonal ED ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Yes. As I said, $E,G,D$ are colinear.

Comment: You do not have enough information. Say you start with the circle, you choose a point $E$, you can calculate point $C$. Now depending on the choice of point $D$ you will get different values of the $\angle AED$. Whatever the choice for $D$ was, you can construct the corresponding $F$, and all other points

Comment: @Andrei That is what I deduced. But the question comes from a book, so I was unsure.

Comment: How do you know $\angle EBC=60^o$?

Comment: $\angle ACE=\angle AEC=30°$. So $\angle CAE=120°$. Since angle at centre is double angle at circumference, $\angle EBC=60°$.

Comment: Given the drawing, F is in the circle.

Comment: @Moti What? How?

Comment: DFE 95 - in such case F need to be in the circle - attempt a drawing. The result could still be 60 as you derive.

Comment: @Moti The Question gives an identical diagram. F is almost certainly outside the circle.

Comment: Did you try a drawing?

Comment: @Moti Yes. I did.

Comment: ECA in your drawing is close to 60 - try to have an actual proper drawing and I believe it will help deriving the solution. The drawing seems to be purposely misleading...